# Ошибка "'recursive_mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type" в C++

Tags: c++, makefile

```
#define OGRE_WQ_MUTEX(name) mutable std::recursive_mutex name
```

Взято из кода движка OGRE3d, компилятор выдает ошибку:

> ".\OGRE\include\OGRE/Threading/OgreThreadDefinesSTD.h:40:42: error:
>   'recursive_mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type"

Компилирую через make-файл.
UPD: Makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -O2 -g -c -w -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++17 -fpermissive
LDFLAGS= --static
SOURCES = main.cpp

#LIBS = -l.\lib\OgreOverlay.lib -l.\lib\OgreMain.lib -l.\lib\OgreBites.lib

LIBS_PATH = \
.\OGRE\lib\
.\OGRE\lib\OGRE\
.\OGRE\lib\OGRE\Samples\

INC_PATHS = \
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Bites\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\HLMS\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\MeshLodGenerator\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Overlay\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Paging\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Plugins\BSPSceneManager\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Plugins\OctreeSceneManager\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Plugins\OctreeZone\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Plugins\ParticleFX\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Plugins\PCZSceneManager\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Plugins\STBICodec\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Property\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\RenderSystems\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\RTShaderSystem\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Terrain\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Threading\
.\OGRE\include\OGRE\Volume\

TARGET = ogre_1.exe

all:    $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -o $(TARGET)  $(LIBS) $(foreach dir,$(INC_PATHS),-I$(dir)) -I. 

clean:
    del /F  $(TARGET)
```

Comment: А компилятор точно его поддерживает?...

Comment: А `#include <mutex>` есть? А `-std=c++11` или выше есть?

Comment: Все есть, последний компилятор и стандарт

Comment: Последний - это какой? Ознакомьтесь с тем, как надо приводить [mcve].